# What is the difference between creating creating functions using function handle and declaring syms?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

It seems that, to create a function f(x,y)=x+y, I can have two approaches.

1. `syms x y; f(x,y) = x+y`
2. `f = @(x,y) x+y`

They seem very similar, and I do not know whether there are some subtle differences.

Comment: Syms is symbolic engine, so expect it to be ~100-1000 times slower. The second one is a numeric function, so as fast as it gets. But the first one will have much more mathematical rigor, as it wont just evaluate the numbers in limited-precision representation, it will do the maths to simplify the equation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, if I need to evaluate the function for inputs or many samples I would opt-in to using the second method (function handles/anonymous functions).

### Method 1: Symbolic Functions

This method allows the function to be evaluated at a specific point/value by using the `subs()`, substitution function. Both plots can be plotted using `fsurf()`.

```
clear;
syms x y
f(x,y) = x+y;
fsurf(f);

subs(f,[x y],[5 5])
```

Variants and offsetting of symbolic functions can be done similarly to anonymous functions/function handles with the one caveat of not needing to include the input parameters in the `@()`.

```
g = f(x,y) + f(x-5,y-5) 
fsurf(g);
```

---

### Method 2: Anonymous Functions/Function Handles

This method allows you to directly input values into the function `f(x,y)`. I prefer anonymous functions because they seem more flexible.

```
clear;
f = @(x,y) x+y;
fsurf(f);

f(5,5)
```

Some cool things you can do is offset and easily add variants of anonymous functions. Inputs can also be in the form of arrays.

```
x = 10; y = 2;
f(x-5,y-5) + f(x,y)

g = @(x,y) f(x,y) + f(x-5,y-20);
fsurf(g);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**